# Simple form multiple select

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I search a solution for select nimulti numbers in array (like sudoku),
I have create a simple_form but chekbox and radio button not work.
my modal (just for one case) is:

```
<%= simple_form_for @sudoku do |f| %>
  <ul>
    <% (1..9).each do |x| %>
      <li>
       <%= f.input :number, label: x %>
      </li>
    <% end %>
   </ul>
    <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

In my db, Sudoku: number is a sting
In my controller I have just:
 validates :number, presence: true,numericality: { only_integer: true}.

I have input, not a number select. If i use checkbox, they not work with my db numbers.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking - could you add more context, such as the models, controllers and what you expect this to look like? Also, what is the actual problem you're having? Is there an error?

Comment: Thanks for your time!, I search a solution for create an array with numbers select. In my controller I have just   validates :number, presence: true, numericality: { only_integer: true}.

Comment: When you use the code you posted, what goes wrong?

Comment: I have input, not a number select. If i use checkbox, they not work with numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved a first party of my problem,

I have an available beautiful number check:

```
<%= simple_form_for @sudoku do |f| %>
    <ul>
    <% (1..9).each do |x| %>
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="checkbox" name="sudoku[number]" id="optionsCheckboxs<%= x %>" value="<%= x %>" autocomplete="off" >
         <%= x %>
    </label>
    </div>
    <% end %>
```

but i don't solved my problem for the multiple selection..

If I add:

`name="sudoku[number][]"`

I have a this rollback problem:

Processing by SudokusController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Cw/......", "sudoku"=>{"number"=>["1"]}, "commit"=>"Submit"}
Unpermitted parameters: number

If you have the solution....I am ok!!!!

Thanks